# How to switch horizontal and vertical scrolling directions

Tags: macos

I would like to know how to switch horizontal and vertical scrolling in OS X 10.9, i.e. when rolling the ball to the left to make the screen go down, and when rolling right to make the screen go up.

Question is **not** how to switch horizontal/vertical direction!
Question is how to switch axes `x` and `y`.

Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hold your mouse sideways?!?

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences > Mouse

Scroll direction check box will be at the top of that window.

Comment: you are short worded, give us bit more please, make it 2 line answer.

Comment: I edited it slightly, but I really doubt this needs a longer answer. I'm not really sure what you think I should elaborate on?

Comment: I know, we just like the more descriptive answers :)

Comment: Scroll direction checkbox swaps up & down directions. What I'm asking is how to swap `x` and `y` axes.

Comment: @BugsBunny for the trackpad, it switches both x,y. I just tested it. If you are using a logitech rollerball type mouse, the answer may lie within that preference pane.